# Patch SUPEE-6788 Caused issues, now unable to revert

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, patches, supee-6788

I recently had problems applying PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-10-27-12-00-16.sh

After looking around I found that replacing my modified .htaccess file with the one that came with the original install then applying the patch would work, and it did. Unfortunately now I'm getting a M2E Pro error.

Also, image uploads have slowed, and oddly my carousel slider on the home page has disappeared.

I've tried to revert the patch but not get this error:

`ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
patching file .htaccess
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file .htaccess.rej
patching file .htaccess.sample
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file .htaccess.sample.rej`

I've tried reverting with both the modified and original .htaccess files with no luck. Any idea on how to revert the patch? Thanks

Comment: Stating the obvious: Did you put back your original modified .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes, I have several backups. could I look at my applid.patches.llist and and restore the listed files for that patch?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently previous patches need to have been applied in order to apply future patches. So rather than revert, i used this toolbox https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox to find out that I had some missing blocks during the M2E Pro upgrade. Instead of running the fix from this toolbox I went to http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php and downloaded the latest version of the M2E Pro extentsion and did a manual install. That was it, all worked perfectly once I copied the files over.